# It is better hide all elements (first) and show the selected one or cycle them and check which might be hidden?

Tags: jquery

This is my code HTML code :

```
​<div id="exp_00" class="example">Hello 0</div>
<div id="exp_01" class="example">Hello 1</div>
<div id="exp_02" class="example">Hello 2</div>
<div id="exp_03" class="example">Hello 3</div>
<div id="exp_04" class="example">Hello 4</div>
```

If I'd like to hide all elements but 03, what do you suggest?

## Method 1 :

```
var myID="03";
$('.example').hide();
$('#exp_' + myID)​​​.show();​
```

## Method 2 :

```
var myID="03";
$('.example').each(function() {
    if($(this).attr('id').split('_')[1]==myID) {
        $(this).show();
    } else {
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
```

with second one, I do 1 cycle, but some split/equality operation. With the first one, also 1 cycle, but I apply the same operator (hide or show) 2 time to the same element.

What can you say about? In your opinion?

Comment: Are you having performance issues that requires you to care? This seems like premature optimisation - go with the option that requires the least code, and only worry about optimising when you actually need to.

Comment: Uhm...nothing special! Just to know for the future, If I have to manage many elements, many times :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.example').hide();
$('#exp_03').show();
```

OR

```
$('.example:not(#exp_03)').hide();
```

**Fudgey's answer**

```
$('#exp_03').show().siblings('.example').hide();
```

Comment: So in this case how siblings() know with are the other elements? By the same classname?

Comment: Edited it, siblings('.example') to match elements with class example

Comment: Ok! But if I don't specify class which elements takes?

Comment: If not specified it will select all the elements contained in the same parent. In this case '.example' is used to filter elements with the same class. (In this case, with or without example will do the same work)